# Sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to find the sum of this series by partial fraction ,I am not able to apply partial fraction here .$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+m)}$.Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your running index is $n$ instead of $i$, here is a simple partial fraction trick

$$ \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+m)} = \frac{1}{m} \left( \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+m-1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)\cdots(n+m)} \right) $$

from which you can initiate the telescoping argument.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&\frac{1}{n(n+1) \cdots (n+m-1)(n+m)} \\ =& \frac{1/m}{n(n+1) \cdots (n+m-1)}-\frac{1/m}{(n+1) \cdots (n+m-1)(n+m)}
\end{eqnarray*}
& then do a telescoping sum.